# angular http call return status 0 statustext error on concurrent call on server after 40 to 45 success call

Tags: php, jquery

I have hosted my website on godday server. I have used datatable ajax server side pagination and place 
searchbox above datatable which is used datatable fnfilter.

Let's say for example I want to search "abc" as soon as I type a it will make http call to server and get data. Then type next character b again it will call to server. It works fine on first 40 to 50 request with status successful after then it will generate status failed and status code 0 and my subdomain is stop responding for 2 to 5 minutes. Meanwhile I try to call webservice through rest client it is working fine irrespective of sub domain not reachable.

[image]

Comment: anything in your php error log?

Comment: 10seconds is a lot of time for a request, you have some optimisation problems

Comment: Could you upload some of your server error logs so we can take a look at them?

Comment: @madalinivascu i have done optimisation.

Comment: @Satishpatel nice only took you ~8 months :)))